# How to update nvidia driver without causing a black screen?

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg

I am using Ubuntu 14.04LTS on a thinkpad with an intel integrate card and a nvidia card.

Everything is fine with nvidia-304 or nvidia-340. However, every time I install newer nvidia driver such as nvidia-352, nvidia-361 or nvidia-367, I would be greeted with a black screen after reboot. I can hear the greeting sound of ubuntu, but cannot see anything. Then I have to remove the nvidia drivers.

All the commands are:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-version

sudo apt-get remove nvidia* --purge
```

Why is this happening? Are there any methods to prevent this problem? Any help would be appreciated!!

**Update:**

I installed nvidia-375 but was still greeted by a black screen.Then I installed nvidia-prime and insert the command 'prime-select intel'. Then the  black screen has gone. But it seems that it simply avoids using the nvidia driver and card instead of solving the real problem. Even if it works, as I prefer bumblebee, I think installing nvidia-prime is not the best solution.

**P.S.**

I have found some answers about how to fix the black screen problem, but none of them can help me install newer version of nvidia driver.

Some other information:

```
lspci |grep 3D
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M]
```

Comment: *"Everything is fine with nvidia-304 "* - there may be no advantage of installing a newer driver.

Comment: It depends on the model of GPU you have. Older GPU's are not supported by newer drivers, as they don't have the features of the newer chips. If your GPU is a bit older, you will get everything you need form 340. Unless you face issues with 340, there is nothing you would get from updating the driver. In short, 340 is fine and modern and should fully support your chip.

Comment: @Takkat The nvidia-304 and nvidia-340 were OK but when I installed cuda-8.0 and run ./deviceQuery, it told me that 'CUDA driver version is insufficient for CUDA runtime version'. I looked up several instructions and their advice are to upgrade nvidia driver. Therefore I met this problem.

Comment: @MarkKirby How can I know which nvidia driver is suitable for my GPU?

Comment: nvidia-304 driver is not compatible with CUDA. In order to avoid this incompatibility, when you install CUDA it automatically installs the compatible Nvidia driver along with it.

Comment: @karel I have tried to let it be installed automatically. But it still gives me a black screen after reboot. The nvidia driver in CUDA is nvidia-346 for cuda-7.0 and something even newer in cuda-8.0, while the newest version supported by my laptop seems to be nvidia-340 now. I have also tried cuda-6.5, whose internal nvidia driver is 340, but the installation failed as it told me that the compiler is insufficient with that version of cuda.

Comment: @MarkKirby As I am using dual-system (Win7 and Ubuntu 14.04), I check the nvidia driver version of Windows. It is nvidia-361, so I think my GPU supports the newer versions.

Answer (score 0):

I had nvidia 378 when I tried to install CUDA 8.0 and during the install process my drivers got downgraded to 375.

This is the process I followed to install them (taken from my notes so I can re-install faster if needed). As mentioned by Mark Kirby do not use xorg ppa.

```
### Add nvidia drivers
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
# More Info on https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-378
```

You will have to research the dependencies between your graphic card, CUDA versions and the software for which you need CUDA. Hopefully you 'll be able to find a sweet spot where all can live together.

P.S. My GPU is nvidia 1050Ti so nvidia-378 was fine (but CUDA still downgraded it). For your graphic card 375/378 may not work (as you already experienced issues).

edit: You didn't mention if you tried `nvidia-375` in your post. If not give it a try to see if it works.